# Accessing Oracle case sensitive ROWID from MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odac

I am having a oracle table where the ROWID column is having data which is duplicate but as the field is case sensitive its considering it as 2 different rows eg. 'Test' and TEST are considered different.

when i am accessing this from MS SQL Server using ODAC, i am getting the error saying System.Data.ConstraintException:Failed to enable constraints.one or more rows contains values violating non null,unique or foreign key constraints.

Any way to query the data using ODAC?

Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Please post the query you are using to access the oracle data

Comment: Hi thanks for the response it got solved using OLEDB driver.

Comment: Voting to close as this question already has been solved by the poster.

Comment: `ROWID` is an Oracle internal unique identifier for a row. The "ROWID column" can **never** contain a value like `TEST`.